# Display only Social Leader board using Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am working on an android game where I want to display a leader board for the user's social circle on Google plus. I have successfully integrated the Google Play Game Services api in my app and it is displaying the leader board. However, Google Services displays two kinds of leader boards -- **Social** and **Public**, I want to display only the Social leader board and not the public.

Is there any way I can do that? Or is there a way I can fetch data from Social leaderboard alone and display it separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured it out myself, luckily. The following code will print the names of your friends present at your social leader board.

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadPlayerCenteredScores(googleApiClient, "*****************", 2, 1, 20).setResultCallback(
    new ResultCallback<LoadScoresResult>(){
        public void onResult(LoadScoresResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int j=0;j<result.getScores().getCount();j++)
            {
                Log.i("score on create",result.getScores().get(j).getScoreHolderDisplayName());

            }
            result.getScores().close();
        }
    });
```

The first parameter is your googleApiClinet which is returned by getApiClient() method.

The second parameter is your  leader board id.

The third parameter is  the time span. Here, 2 indicates TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME

The fourth parameter is the leaderBoardCollection. Here, 1 indicates COLLECTION_SOCIAL.

You can use same code for obtaining other information such as formatted rank, scores, and profile picture url. Just replace getScoreHolderDisplayName() with other appropriate methods.